# Read Text file and access elements of Text file separately in c#

Tags: c#

I am reading a text file consisting of two columns (contains x and y coordinates):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Point(x,y).txt"))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\t' };
                string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(parts[i]);
                }

            }

        }
        // Suspend the screen.
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to read the data in text file separately in two different variables
How do I access each value?

Comment: Show us the sample content of your input file and what expected output you want from it

Comment: _"How do I access each element?"_ -- meaning what, exactly? How does the code you posted _not_ accomplish this? Your question is unclear and cannot be usefully answered without a good [mcve] and a clear explanation of what _specifically_ you are unable to solve.

Comment: _"I want to **access** each **row element separately** for plotting"_ - a text file isn't a DB

Comment: I mean to say I want to read the elements of each row separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where Linq can come to the rescue.  You can read all the lines and parse directly with Linq. I am assuming you have a tab delimited text file based on the line.Split you are doing.  You can create a new anonymous type to capture row/line in your text file.  You then have access to the fields as seen when writing out to the console, by looping through each item/anonymous type in the list.  Make sure you have the using System.Linq namespace included which is usually there by default.

```
var records = File
            .ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\saira\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Point(x,y).txt")
            .Select(record => record.Split('\t'))
            .Select(record => new
            {
                x = record[0],
                y = record[1]
            }).ToList();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The x coordinate is:{record.x}, and the y coordinate is {record.y}");
        }
```